# Set enable/disable on menuitem depending on data modification

Tags: javafx

I am new on java and javafx. I made a simple application on javafx using mvc pattern. This application handles a person table and is structured in this way.
Model containing the persons data
View containing a menu 
View containing the tableview of the persons, the detail of the selected person and three buttons (New --> add new person, Edit --> change a person, Delete --> cancel a person
View that allows to change contents of the selected person

All works fine, but I have a problem with the menu. I would like to handle the menuitem 'Save' changing the 'Disable' flag  in the way that it set to 'false' or 'true' programmatically, depending on if the user changed the data or not, but I do not know how can pass it from a scene to another.

I have been searching a lot on this web site and on other sites without any result.
I have found a question on stackoverflow called '**Toggle enable/disable on Menuitem javafx from another scene?**' that probably could solve my question, but unfortunately I did not understand the solution.
Is there somebody who can help me?
Thank you in advance.
Alberto

Comment: You're using mvc so there should be some property in your model that contains the info if the data was modified or not since the last save. (or at least some way of computing the info). Since your model should update the view accordingly or make the property observable, e.g. using a `BooleanProperty` which would allow you to simply bind the `disable` property.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: @Fabian The problem is not to know if user changed data or not, but to pass the menuitem 'save' to the controller that handles the update of the tableview and not the menu. When I try to set the menuitem, I find a compilation error because this object is not seen by this controller.

Comment: So you're using FXML + Controller? You didn't mention that. Add some code snippets of both so we can help.

Comment: @Fabian I have solved this problem, I applied a solution explained on the following thread: ' Accessing FXML controller class' on the stackoverflow.com. I applied the first solution and it worked very well.

Comment: Thanks to all that spent some time to help me